# GOOGLE MAPS API MARKER IS NOT BOUNCING

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For more that one hour I was trying to repair my code. Still I don't know why it's not working. I hope that you can help me.

Here's a link:
[MyCode](https://pastebin.com/raw/i666k97q)

I have a problem with this part:

```
google.maps.event.addListner(marker2, 'click', function(){
marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);});

google.maps.event.addListner(marker2, 'click', function(){

marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.STOP);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, you have misspelled `.addListner`

```
google.maps.event.addListner(marker2, 'click', function(){
    marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);});
google.maps.event.addListner(marker2, 'click', function(){
    marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.STOP);});
```

It should be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function(){
    marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function(){
    marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.STOP);});
```

The correct spelling is `.addListener`.

**EDIT**

After reading through your code and trying to figure out what you wanted to do I think I understand. Try making the following changes to your code:

```
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 52.2317554, lng: 21.0061516 },
    map: map,
    title: 'PKiN',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

Then remove both listeners and add this instead:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
    if (marker2.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker2.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }            
});
```

This shoud make the marker drop at first, and when clicked it shoud bounce until you click it again.

Comment: can you check your key again, to make sure you have the correct one. If it's the correct one, try to regenerate a new one and paste this in your code

Comment: It's good one, because every other thing works, only this two functions are not working. But i'll generate new key as you said./edit: generated new key, still this one marker is not bouncing.

Comment: can you check your console for errors then, is the map showing at all?

Comment: everything is working just not this bouncing. I can see map, and other staff that I wrote. There is no errors, but still this one thing is not working. btw, thank you for response!